# Async celery task with group/chord of arbitrary size

Tags: python, celery

Let's say I have the following Celery code:

```
from celery import Celery, group

app = Celery()
app.conf.update(
    broker_url=some_broker,
    result_backend=some_backend,
)


@app.task
def generate_list(n):
    return list(range(n))


@app.task
def double_it(value):
    return value * 2


@app.task
def tsum(value):
    return sum(value
```

It's easy enough to create a group or a chord that produces an async result which yields the actual results:

```
>>> group([double_it.s(x) for x in range(5)])().get()
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]

>>> (group([double_it.s(x) for x in range(5)]) | tsum.s())().get()
20
```

However, I can't figure out how to do something similar with an arbitrarily sized list without making parts synchronous.  I've tried this:

```
>>> @app.task
... def make_group(items):
...     return group([double_it.s(x) for x in items])()

>>> @app.task
... def make_chord(items):
...     return chord(
...         [double_it.s(x) for x in items],
...         tsum.s(),
...     )()

>>> (generate_list.s(5) | make_group.s())().get()
['5d23a31f-6da3-4fec-8bd0-6e57a4da9c43',
 [[['7d2cf535-96d6-40fe-b76b-d118aaffbc95', None], None],
  [['5ef96f17-8ac7-4c1b-a794-c0e6e85c2b8c', None], None],
  [['ec595134-76af-40e8-a211-d2592acd250f', None], None],
  [['146b0da2-c9bf-49c3-a259-a98808c2b1af', None], None],
  [['9ad3eb4a-92e2-4194-ae9f-3aa17dbf0333', None], None]]]

>>> (generatelist.s(5) | make_chord.s())().get()
    [['045a5130-cc33-4ba7-99cc-58dd94675515',
      ['771f444a-2df5-4436-96e0-6e1774c2b437',
       [[['4b88c20c-f5ac-485e-aae8-b562c5865cd5', None], None],
        [['b5890545-48eb-49d9-8a5b-d638381ce3ab', None], None],
        [['e8f19456-5b29-4d2f-b8e2-d81cb9f1c258', None], None],
        [['aa95ba0f-04d3-4bc1-a34a-905076fe4cb7', None], None],
        [['155f2183-e673-4921-be4e-568b5011b1e9', None], None]]]],
     None]
```

...which appears to return the various task ID's in a strange, nested list that includes a bunch of `None`s.  Trying to make a chord results in an error about not being able to JSON serialize a `GroupResult`, which presumably is because `make_group` is immediately returning and moving on to the next task instead of a chord being built.  Making a chord explicitly (instead of implicitly with a group -> task chain) gets rid of the error, but you still get the immediate return with the task ID's.

The only way I've figured out to get around this is to wait for the results of the chain, then use the task ID's to create an async result for the proper task.

```
>>> from celery.result import AsyncResult
>>> task_id = (generate_list.s(5) | make_chord.s())().get()[0][0]
>>> AsyncResult(task_id).get()
20
```

How are you supposed to make this work without resorting to grabbing the appropriate task ID and then creating an `AsyncResult` from it?